# How to get top Fragment in backstack from DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-dialogfragment, fragment-backstack

I'm using navigation to navigate between fragments.

And I have a DialogFragment, it can called from from many fragment like this:

```
 val dialog = FragmentDialog
 dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "home_fragment")
```

And I want to know dialogfragment called by which fragment

I tried with   *FragmentManager.backStackEntryCount*   but it's seem doesn't work

Can I have a advice for this problem ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this ..

1. You can just Pass a key in `Bundle` to your `DialogFragment` to check which Fragment opened it ..
2. If your Dialog fragment a attached to a `fragment` in each case you can just use `getParentFragment()`  . `getParentFragment()` will return the instance of that fragment. If its attached to activity then `getParentFragment()` will be null so watch out for this case also .
3. you can also use `getTag()` from where it was open byt passing different tags to transaction .